# Как выполнить функцию только по условию?

Tags: javascript, функции

Пытаюсь сделать кликер, в котором при нажатии на `Button` отнимается количество здоровья у врага. Но когда счётчик доходит до `0`, он не останавливается, и продолжает убывать: `-1`, `-2`. Как этого избежать?

Пытался через условие `if`: функция вообще перестала выполняться и имя функции пишет, что не определено.

Почему так происходит, и как реализовать такую идею?

До тех пор, пока не начал ставить условия, все нормально работало.

А ещё, хотел бы ограничить размер окна браузера, когда пользователь открывает эту страницу, если это возможно.

```js
let result = 100;


if (result >= 0) {


  function calc() {

    // let b = Number(document.getElementById("s2nd").value);
    // let a = Number(document.getElementById("f1st").value);
    result = result - 1;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  }

  function calc1() {

    // let b = Number(document.getElementById("s2nd").value);
    // let a = Number(document.getElementById("f1st").value);
    result = result - 20;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;

  } else {
    result.textContent("Вы победили")
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}

.big {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<!-- 
            Введите первое число <input id="f1st" type="Number">
            <br>
            <br>
            Введите второе число <input id="s2nd" type="Number">
    <br> -->

<button onclick="calc()">Простой Удар</button>
<button onclick="calc1()">Магия</button>
<br>
<br>
<p>Ваш результат </p>
<p class="big" id="result">100</p>
<br>
```

Comment: Положи код в тело вопроса.

Comment: Я добавил код, может можно разобраться, что с ним не так ? Я учу программирование неделю . Думаю из кода понятно, что я хотел сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в том, что вы вызываете функцию (которая снимает очки) в любом случае сработает (снимет очки). Условиу `if (result < 0)` надо засунуть внутрь этих функций (которые снимают очки).

```js
function go(addr) {
  window.open(addr, "MyWin", "menubar=yes,width=380,height=430");
}

let result = 100;

function checkWin() {
  if (result <= 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = 'You won!';
  }
}

function calc() {
  if (result > 0) {
    // let b = Number(document.getElementById("s2nd").value);
    // let a = Number(document.getElementById("f1st").value);
    result--;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  }
  checkWin();
}

function calc1() {
  if (result > 0) {
    // let b = Number(document.getElementById("s2nd").value);
    // let a = Number(document.getElementById("f1st").value);
    result -= 20;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  }
  checkWin();
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
}

.big {
  color: red;
  font-size: 32px;
}
```

```html
<br>
<!-- 
        Введите первое число <input id="f1st" type="Number">
        <br>
        <br>
        Введите второе число <input id="s2nd" type="Number">
<br> -->

<button onclick="calc()">Простой Удар</button>
<button onclick="calc1()">Магия</button>
<br>
<br>
<p>Ваш результат </p>
<p class="big" id="result">100</p>
<br>
```

Comment: Это потрясающе. Работает !